# .net Core Identity w/o EntityFramework using int ids

Tags: .net-core, identity

I'm trying to create a .net Core solution using Identity w/o EntityFramework but with integer ids (UserId and RoleId).  I've followed this basic setup for creating the solution and removing EF (https://taherchhabra.github.io/jekyll/update/2016/09/22/aspnet-core-identity-without-entityframework.html) but this still has the stupid Guid id column for the Users.  When I try to change it I run into an issue in creating my `UserStore` because it inherits from `IUserStore<User>` which requires that I implement

`Task<User> FindByIdAsync(string userId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)`

which or course means the Id value is a string instead of an int.

I have read several things talking about how to change EF-based solutions to use ints and I dug into how EF does that but it is all based on EF classes which use a `TKey`.

I tried to create my own IUserStore to change the strings to ints but the project wouldn't even spin up (it would compile fine but when I tried to run it locally it would exit before completing spin up).

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?  I've search quite a bit and can't find anything.

**Edit:**
What I have done so far is create my own UserStore and RollStore (which are basically just copies of the originals which I will tweak once I get working).  In my HomeController I added the following:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<models.User> _userManager;
    public HomeController(UserManager<models.User> userManager)
    {
      _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var user = new models.User();
        if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);

        return View();
    }

}
```

This is basically a "is it plugged in" test which I can step through in the debugger.

In my `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddSingleton<IUserStore<User>, UserStore>();
services.AddSingleton<IRoleStore<Role>, RoleStore>();

services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

This will actually work (debugging through my endpoint, the `user` is populated correctly).  But, if I look close I realize that `IUserStore` and `IRoleStore` are the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` versions which means I'm still dependent on those contracts and am required to use the Guid for an Id.

If I force the issue, using

```
 services.AddSingleton<SandboxCoreDapper.Identity.Interfaces.IUserStore<User>, UserStore>();
 services.AddSingleton<SandboxCoreDapper.Identity.Interfaces.IRoleStore<Role>, RoleStore>();
```

then when I try to hit my endpoint, the UserManager will fail to resolve:

"Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[SandboxCoreDapper.Models.User]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[SandboxCoreDapper.Models.User]'."

**Edit 2**
I found this interesting discussion:  https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/493

Based on that I've gone ahead and created my own `RoleManager` and `UserManager` which basically just extend the Identity versions:

```
namespace SandboxCoreDapper.Identity.Services
{

    public class UserManager<TUser> : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager<TUser> where TUser : class
    {

        public UserManager(
                sandyId.IUserStore<TUser> store, // my version of IUserStore
                IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor, 
                IPasswordHasher<TUser> passwordHasher, 
                IEnumerable<IUserValidator<TUser>> userValidators, 
                IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<TUser>> passwordValidators, 
                ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer, 
                IdentityErrorDescriber errors, 
                IServiceProvider services, 
                ILogger<UserManager<TUser>> logger)
            :base(store, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, services, logger)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

and likewise for `RoleManager`.

Then I added to `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
     .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
     .AddUserManager<SandboxCoreDapper.Identity.Services.UserManager<User>>()
     .AddRoleManager<SandboxCoreDapper.Identity.Services.RoleManager<Role>>()
            ;
```

So far so good...

Comment: try having a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36184856/authentication-and-authorization-without-entity-framework-in-asp-net-5-mvc-6

Comment: Thanks @ganders  .  I have read through that question but I'm stuck on the  "You can use the built in UserManager if you implement the userstore and rolestore, it is not required to implement that yourself unless you have other reasons for doing so."  I am trying to do this but the `UserManager` keeps pointing to the default Identity `UserStore` and I can't figure out how to point it to my own version.  The only article I can find on the subject is for Identity 2 --pre Core

Comment: did you register your UserStore in the startup.cs file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest I could come to an answer for this is this git project:  https://github.com/grandchamp/Identity.Dapper

It is still in process and I am working with the project owner on some enhancements but for anyone else who stumbles on this question, right now that project is your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

This is in response to my comment, and your question/comment:

Just declare your own UserStore, then register it in the Startup.cs.

Here's my implementation of the UserStore to accommodate this scenario:

```
public class UserStore : IUserPasswordStore<Login>, IUserEmailStore<Login>, IUserPhoneNumberStore<Login>
    {
        private readonly IAccountRepo _accountRepo;

        public UserStore(IAccountRepo accountRepo)
        {
            _accountRepo = accountRepo;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }

        public async Task<string> GetUserIdAsync(Login user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(user.Username);
        }

        public async Task<string> GetUserNameAsync(Login user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(user.Username);
        }

        public Task SetUserNameAsync(Login user, string userName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task<string> GetNormalizedUserNameAsync(Login user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public async Task SetNormalizedUserNameAsync(Login user, string normalizedName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await Task.FromResult(user.Username = normalizedName.ToLower());
        }

        public async Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(Login user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await _accountRepo.CreateLogin(user);
            return IdentityResult.Success;
        }

        public async Task<IdentityResult> UpdateAsync(Login user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await _accountRepo.UpdateLogin(user.LoginId, user.Email, true);
            return IdentityResult.Success;
        }

        public Task<IdentityResult> DeleteAsync(Login user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public async Task<Login> FindByIdAsync(string userId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return await _accountRepo.GetUser(userId);
        }

        public async Task<Login> FindByNameAsync(string normalizedUserName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return await _accountRepo.GetUser(normalizedUserName);
        }

        public async Task SetPasswordHashAsync(Login user, string passwordHash, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (user.LoginId != 0)
            {
                await _accountRepo.ChangePassword(user.Email, user.Username, passwordHash);
            }

            user.PasswordHash = passwordHash;
        }

        public async Task<string> GetPasswordHashAsync(Login user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(user.PasswordHash);
        }

        public async Task<bool> HasPasswordAsync(Login user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.PasswordHash) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Salt));
        }

        public Task SetEmailAsync(Login user, string email, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task<string> GetEmailAsync(Login user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(user.Email);
        }

        public async Task<bool> GetEmailConfirmedAsync(Login user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(user.EmailConfirmed);
        }

        public Task SetEmailConfirmedAsync(Login user, bool confirmed, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(user.EmailConfirmed = confirmed);
        }

        public Task<Login> FindByEmailAsync(string normalizedEmail, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task<string> GetNormalizedEmailAsync(Login user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task SetNormalizedEmailAsync(Login user, string normalizedEmail, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(user.Email = normalizedEmail.ToLower());
        }

        public Task SetPhoneNumberAsync(Login user, string phoneNumber, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task<string> GetPhoneNumberAsync(Login user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task<bool> GetPhoneNumberConfirmedAsync(Login user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task SetPhoneNumberConfirmedAsync(Login user, bool confirmed, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

And the Startup.cs ConfigureServices method:

```
services.AddSingleton<IUserStore<Login>, UserStore>();
```